# Removing axis labelling for one geom when multiple geoms are present

Tags: r, ggplot2

All I want is this R code to display the names of players inside the "topName" while hiding the names inside the "otherNames" by plotting both of them using two different geom_col().

> epldata <- read.csv(file = 'epldata.csv') 
>   epldata$srno <- c(1:461)
>       attach(epldata) 
>   points <- epldata[order(-fpl_points),] 
>   detach(epldata)
>
> topNames[24:461]<-NA epldata$topNames <- topNames
>   topPoints[24:461]<-NA epldata$topPoints <- topPoints
>
> epldata$otherNames <- NA epldata$otherNames[24:461] <-
>   as.character(points$name[c(24:461)]) epldata$otherPoints <- NA
>   epldata$otherPoints[24:461] <-
>   as.numeric(points$fpl_points[c(24:461)])
>
> ggplot(data = epldata)+   geom_col(aes(x=epldata$topNames,
>   y=epldata$topPoints), fill = "red", alpha = 1) +
>   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
>   annotate("text", x=epldata$topNames, y=-50, #epldata$topPoints, 
>              label = epldata$topNames, fontface = 1, size = 2, hjust = 0)+   geom_col(aes(x=epldata$otherNames, y=epldata$otherPoints), fill
>   = "gray", alpha = 0.3)+   theme(legend.position = "none")+   #theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+   xlab("Player Names")+   ylab("FPL Points")+   guides(fill=FALSE,
>   color=FALSE, guide = FALSE) +   coord_flip() +   theme(axis.text.y =
>   element_blank(),
>           axis.ticks.y = element_blank())

[image: My output image here]

[This is the kind of output I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7oug.png) but without using the Annotate Hack that I am currently using but directly plotting the names on the axis.

Update : have added the entire code and the link to the data set is below :
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KTitWDcLIBmeBsz8mLcHXDIyhQLZnlhS

Comment: Also the data with fill = "green" is actually showing as red on the plot and vice versa

Comment: Please provide [some or all of epldata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Also I suspect that you data are "wide" rather than "long". ggplot2 works better with one column for the labels (otherPoints, topPoints) and another for their values. And you should not be using `$` inside `aes()`, just the column name.

Comment: use `colour = I("green")` to get green

Answer (score 1):

Once you've created a list of topNames, you can use `scale_x_continuous` to display only these axis labels:

```r
scale_x_discrete(breaks = topNames)
```

Also, rather than using two separate `geom_col()` geometries, you can create a new "highlight" column in the dataframe and use that with the fill and alpha aesthetics:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# read data from google drive
id <- "1KTitWDcLIBmeBsz8mLcHXDIyhQLZnlhS" #google file ID
epldata <- read.csv(sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", id),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

N <- 24 #number of players to highlight

#get list of names of top N players
topNames <- epldata %>% 
  arrange(-fpl_points) %>% 
  head(N) %>% 
  pull(name)
#> Warning: package 'bindrcpp' was built under R version 3.5.1

# make variable for highlighting
epldata <- epldata %>% 
  mutate(highlight = ifelse(name %in% topNames, TRUE, FALSE))

ggplot(data = epldata,
       aes(x = name, y = fpl_points, fill = highlight, alpha = highlight)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(guide = FALSE,
                    values = c("gray", "red")) +
  scale_alpha_manual(guide = FALSE,
                     values = c(0.4, 1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = topNames) + #use breaks to determine axis labels
  coord_flip() +
  ylab("FPL Points") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
       axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

<sup>Created on 2018-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

[image: including only some axis labels]